# Target a Chrome Extension using AppleScript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript

I've run into a bit of roadblock and I could use a suggestion. Part of a script that I'm writing, I'm targeting an extension in the Chrome brower to take a full page screen shot of a site. I've been able to identify the element using the Accessibility inspector but I can't figure out how to click on the element. I've tried several variants of the attached code without much luck.

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Google Chrome"
    tell group "Extensions" of group "BBC - Homepage - Google Chrome" of window "BBC - Homepage - Google Chrome"
        click (first button where its accessibility description = "Full Page Screen Capture")
    end tell
end tell
```

end tell

as well as

```
tell application "System Events"
delay 1
tell process "Google Chrome"
    click UI element "Full Page Screen Capture" of group "Extensions" of group "BBC - Homepage - Google Chrome" of window "BBC - Homepage - Google Chrome"
end tell
```

end tell

Also: I can target other elements in the Extensions group (i.e. Window Resizer) but this one does not want to cooperate.[image]

Any suggestion would be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try a different extension or use CDP by running `chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222` (or a different port) then use any CDP client to send Page.captureScreenshot ([a random example](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Take-page-screenshot)), the screenshot height is limited to 16384px IIRC. Don't forget to exit Chrome completely beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we open a blank new tab in Google Chrome. Less UI elements is good for analysis. then we run the code(XXX) below:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
        set uiElems to entire contents
    end tell
end tell
```

Search "screen" in the text output, we see line like this:

> button "Full Page Screen Capture" of group "Extensions" of group "New
>   Tab - Google Chrome" of window "New Tab - Google Chrome" of
>   application process "Google Chrome",

So we know

the button is in group(Extensions),

the group(Ext...) is in group(New Tab...),

the group(New tab...)is in window...

So we test the code below:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        tell window "New Tab - Google Chrome"
            tell group "New Tab - Google Chrome"
                tell group "Extensions"
                    tell button "Full Page Screen Capture"
                        click
                        --perform action "AXPress"
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

It works. But we see the name of the active tab "New Tab - Google Chrome" is in the code, so if we go to another tab, the code doesn't work.
So we need to know how to get the name of the active tab of the front window. I did a lot of test. Finally I find answer on this [page](https://riptutorial.com/applescript/example/32605/get-the-title-of-the-current-page-in-safari-or-google-chrome).

```
osascript -e 'tell app "google chrome" to get the title of the active tab of window 1'
```

Then I put it in my AppleScript, test the code below:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        set theTitle to do shell script "osascript -e 'tell app \"google chrome\" to get the title of the active tab of window 1'" as text
        set theTitle to theTitle & " - Google Chrome"
        --note the example title is "New Tab - Google Chrome". Don't forget to attach " - Google Chrome"
        tell window theTitle
            tell group theTitle
                tell group "Extensions"
                    tell button "Full Page Screen Capture"
                        --click
                        perform action "AXPress"
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Most of the time, this version of code works, BUT sometimes it doesn't work. I run code(XXX) at this tab, interesting, the button name changed from "Full Page Screen Capture" to "Full Page Screen Capture

Has access to this site" Note it inserts a "\r" after the word "Capture". So we know the Title of Window may change, and the button name may change. So I try to make a handler. Test the code below:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 0.3
end tell

try
    set buttonName to "Full Page Screen Capture"
    fullPageScreenshot(buttonName)
on error
    set buttonName to "Full Page Screen Capture
Has access to this site"
    --note here is a "\r"
    fullPageScreenshot(buttonName)
end try

on fullPageScreenshot(buttonName)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Google Chrome"
            set theTitle to do shell script "osascript -e 'tell app \"google chrome\" to get the title of the active tab of window 1'" as text
            delay 0.2
            set theTitle to theTitle & " - Google Chrome"
            --note the example title is "New Tab - Google Chrome". Don't forget to attach " - Google Chrome"
            tell window theTitle
                tell group theTitle
                    tell group "Extensions"
                        tell button buttonName
                            --click
                            perform action "AXPress"
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end fullPageScreenshot
```

Now this version code, I test it more than 20 times, it always work. I do not use this extension too frequently. My Google Chrome version is Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit); and MacOS 10.12.6. Please let me know if this code works on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! Very, very helpful and informative. I didn't know you call the perform action "AXPress" for starters. The rest of your answer was just added bonus.